# Analysis Services Dimension members - change permission by script

Tags: scripting, ssas, bids

How can I change custom access to dimension data for some role using scripts or XMLA file or some .net code without UI such as SQL Server Management Studio or Business Intelegence Developer Studio?
The goal is to have ability to change permissions from another application via web-interface or some bat file etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can automate role setup with AMO like this article shows:
https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/ssas-using-amo-to-secure-analysis-service-cube/

But you might also consider dynamic security before you try another approach:
http://hccmsbi.blogspot.com/2007/08/implementing-user-specific-security-in.html

Comment: Also I found this usefull article: https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/03/using-custom-data-to-securely-access-analysis-services-data-via-performancepoint/

Comment: @D0dger careful with CustomData. I would recommend that only service accounts be members of that CustomData role because if users are members of that role they can edit the connection string and change the CustomData property to anything they want. That would let them access anything they want.